# How to stabilize the output size of TransposedConv2d in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, deconvolution, max-pooling

I have an encoder-decoder regression network written in PyTorch which takes RGB images as input. Output is a 2D image that supposed to have the same size as the input.

For the case of patch-based analysis that I use 224x224 sized rgb patches, everything works well. But when it comes to variable sized inputs such as 681x1024 or 777x900, things start to get messy. Because the output size is almost always unequal to the input size and this is hinders me from implementing the structure I intend to. Here is why:

[image: Multi-Branch, Hybrid Fusion Network]

Lets say I would like to build a **multi-branch, hybrid fusion** network like above ([taken from this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.05356.pdf)). In this network, one of the outputs of the global branch becomes a part of the input of local branch. In other words, **size of GUIDANCE MAP should be equal to LIDAR image.**

Now, my intention is to have the same functionality with variable sized input. My two branches has the structures

```
self.global = nn.Sequential(Conv2d(3, 16, 9, same_padding=True, bn=bn),
                            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
                            Conv2d(16, 32, 7, same_padding=True, bn=bn),
                            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
                            Conv2d(32, 16, 7, same_padding=True, bn=bn),
                            Conv2d(16, 8, 7, same_padding=True, bn=bn),

                            DeConv2d(8, 8, 3, stride=2, same_padding=True),
                            Conv2d(8, 4, 7, same_padding=True, bn=bn),
                            DeConv2d(4, 4, 3, stride=2, same_padding=True),
                            Conv2d(4, 1, 4, same_padding=False, bn=bn))

self.local = nn.Sequential(Conv2d(3, 24, 5, same_padding=True, bn=bn),
                        nn.MaxPool2d(2),
                        Conv2d(24, 48, 3, same_padding=True, bn=bn),
                        nn.MaxPool2d(2),
                        Conv2d(48, 24, 3, same_padding=True, bn=bn),
                        Conv2d(24, 12, 3, same_padding=True, bn=bn),

                        DeConv2d(12, 12, 3, stride=2, same_padding=True),
                        Conv2d(12, 6, 3, same_padding=True, bn=bn),
                        DeConv2d(6, 6, 3, stride=2, same_padding=True),
                        Conv2d(6, 1, 4, same_padding=False, bn=bn))
```

They work properly when I need to **fuse** their **output**, since their output have the same size. But when I want to **fuse the input image with the output of the global network**, I get the

```
runtime error : invalid argument 0: Sizes of tensors must match
except in dimension 1. 
Got 294 and 292 in dimension 2 at ...
```

I am aware that these size changes are caused by TransposedConv2d functions inability to restore the resolution that have been decreased by MaxPool2d with an exact precision. But I wonder if there is a way to restore the size explicitly and dynamically.

*TLDR; I would like to **restore the image resolution decreased by MaxPool2d using TransposedConv2d** for inputs with uneven sizes such as 681x1024 or 777x900.*

I appreciate any help or suggestion.

Comment: This is what I saw on keras https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet/blob/master/keras_retinanet/layers/_misc.py#L109 but I never try it on pytorch though

Comment: Hmmm. So they used interpolation. Let me try and see if that works for my problem

Comment: The idea is use an image `resize` function. I think for pytorch, convert the target tensor (292) to numpy then use `cv2.resize` each element in batch to be same as the source tensor (294) and convert back to torch tensor is possible.

Comment: That would be extremely slow. :/ PyTorch has its own way for resizing tensors so that should not be the issue, I can still use interpolation. My concern is whether if it is possible to resize images with such tiny size changes such as (680,1024) -> (681,1024). FWIW I'll give it a shot